# Remove word extension in python

Tags: python, string

I've got a text with several words. I want to remove all the derivative extension of the words. For example I want to remove extensions -ed -ing and keep the initial verb. If I i have the verifying or verified to keep verify f.e. I found the method strip in python which removes a specific string from the beginning or end of a string but is not what exactly I want. Is there any library which does such a thing in python for example?

I've tried to perform the code from proposed post and I've noticed a weird trimming in several words. For example I've got the following text

```
 We goin all the way βπƒβ΅οΈβ΅οΈ        
 Think ive caught on to a really good song ! Im writing π       
 Lookin back on the stuff i did when i was lil makes me laughh π‚       
 I sneezed on the beat and the beat got sicka       
 #nashnewvideo http://t.co/10cbUQswHR       
 Homee βοΈβοΈβοΈπ΄      
 So much respect for this man , truly amazing guy βοΈ @edsheeran  
 http://t.co/DGxvXpo1OM"        
 What a day ..      
 RT @edsheeran: Having some food with @ShawnMendes      
 #VoiceSave  christina π        
 Im gunna make the βοΈ sign my signature pose       
 You all are so beautiful .. π soooo beautiful      
 Thought that was a really awesome quote        
 Beautiful things don't ask for attention"""
```

And after the use of the following code (also I remove non latin characters and urls)

```
 we  goin  all  the  way 
 think  ive  caught  on  to  a  realli  good  song  im  write 
 lookin  back  on  the  stuff  i  did  when  i  wa  lil  make  me  laughh 
 i  sneez  on  the  beat  and  the  beat  got  sicka 
 nashnewvideo 
 home 
 so  much  respect  for  thi  man  truli  amaz  guy 
 what  a  day 
 rt  have  some  food  with 
 voicesav  christina 
 im  gunna  make  the  sign  my  signatur  pose 
 you  all  are  so  beauti  soooo  beauti 
 thought  that  wa  a  realli  awesom  quot 
 beauti  thing  dont  ask  for  attent
```

For example it trims beautiful to beauti and quote to quot really to realli. My code is the following:

```
 reader = csv.reader(f)
    print doc
    for row in reader:
        text =  re.sub(r"(?:\@|https?\://)\S+", "", row[2])
        filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, text)
        out = text.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
        out = re.sub("[\W\d]", " ", out.strip())
        word_list = out.split()
        str1 = ""
        for verb in word_list:
                 verb = verb.lower()
                 verb = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer().stem_word(verb)
                 str1 = str1+" "+verb+" " 
        list.append(str1)
        str1 = "\n"
```

Comment: Yeah stem is the word I was looking for. I ve tried the example of the  post proposed but I noticed a heavily word trimming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead `stemmer` you can use `lemmatizer`. Here's an example with python NLTK:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

s = """
 You all are so beautiful soooo beautiful
 Thought that was a really awesome quote
 Beautiful things don't ask for attention
 """

wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
print " ".join([wnl.lemmatize(i) for i in s.split()]) #You all are so beautiful soooo beautiful Thought that wa a really awesome quote Beautiful thing don't ask for attention
```

In some cases, it may not do what you expect:

```
print wnl.lemmatize('going') #going
```

Then you can combine both approaches: `stemming` and `lemmatization`.

Comment: I am getting the following result with lemmatizer: You all are so beautiful soooo beautiful Thought that wa a really awesome quote Beautiful thing don't ask for attention

Comment: Is it wise to use lemmatization first followed by stemming?

Answer (score 3):

your question is a little bit general, but if you have a static text that is already defined, the best way is to write your own `stemmer`. because the `Porter` and `Lancaster` stemmers follow their own rules for stripping affixes, and the `WordNet lemmatizer` only removes affixes if the resulting word is in its dictionary.

You can write something like:

```
import re


def stem(word):
    for suffix in ['ing', 'ly', 'ed', 'ious', 'ies', 'ive', 'es', 's', 'ment']:
        if word.endswith(suffix):
            return word[:-len(suffix)]
    return word


def stemmer(phrase):
    for word in phrase:
        if stem(word):
            print re.findall(r'^(.*)(ing|ly|ed|ious|ies|ive|es|s|ment)$', word)
```

so for "processing processes" you will have:

```
 >> stemmer('processing processes')
[('process', 'ing'),('process', 'es')]
```